# Flow3 - ManyToMany Fluid Template hidden Fields (PropertyMapping)

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, fluid, typo3-flow

I've a Questionary Model and a Question Model, connected by a ManyToMany relation.
Now I'm building an draggable UI (jQueryUI) were questions can be added to a questionary.

On the right side every question item is represented as a (hidden) textfield containing its __identity:

```
<f:form.textfield property="questions" name="questions" value="{question}" />
```

On the left side I have a form as the drop target for the question items.
When this form is submitted, flow3 reponsed with this error message:

> 1297759968: Exception while property mapping for target type
>   "MC\QuestionaryBuilder\Domain\Model\Questionary", at property path
>   "questions": It is not allowed to map property "__identity".
>
> You need to use
>   $propertyMappingConfiguration->allowProperties('__identity') to enable
>   mapping of this property.

How can I get it work? :(

**Edit**

When I use this multiple select box I can get it work!

But I need a draggable UI where every question item is a hidden textfield containing the UID.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your form with fluid all elements between the open and end tag of `form` are *trusted properties* (same kind of "modification allowed"-properties). Fluid protect your forms, or more to say: objects, for manipulations. Because your dropzone is empty (i guess) at the beginning, these fields are not marked as "manipulation allowed" fields. That is what your error message wants to say.

It also looks like you are not adding a question to the property questions, instead you are trying to **set** questions to a question-object that's why your error says you'r trying to manipulate the *identity* of questions. You should try `<f:form.textfield name="questions[]" value="{question}" />`

In the error message you also find a hint you may want to know:
You can mark fields as "manipulation allowed" on your own by using the property-mapping-configuration.

You can find the [documentation here](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/PropertyMapping.html).

**Example:**
This is a rough example how to use a property-mapping-configuration.

```php
protected function initializeCreateAction() {
        $configuration = $this->arguments['newQuestionary']->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
        //You can do: $configuration->allowAllProperties();
        //Or more specify:
        $configuration->allowProperties('questions');
}

public function createAction($newQuestionary){
        //...
        $this->myRepository->create($newQuestionary);
        //...
}
```

---

Maybe you can give us more information especially a sample code how your html (and maybe model) looks like.

*Also nice to know:*

- You can use `<f:form.hidden .../>` for hidden-field.
- If you use `<f:form.someTag property="myPro" />` the name- and value-attribute will be set (and override).